# MSVC++ Exception 0x80000003 In Different Language

Tags: c++, mfc, runtime-error

I have some software that I've helped modify.  We took the application from 32 to MFC to 64 bit MFC.  It's been a pretty big project, but we are having this one really strange issue.  My installer works on all of our computers here, the application works and doesn't have issues; however, when our customers try to install the program, the program immediately crashes.  Thinking it was a fluke issue, we asked them to install it on a few of their PCs and all of them are having this issue.  We've additionally tried running our PCs in the given language as well as install an operating system in the given language to test the issue to no avail.

Scratching our heads we've tried a number of different things, but I think the real key is going to be with the Event Viewer information.  We get the exception code 0x80000003 for module with path C:\Windows\System32\Kernelbase.dll and C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll.  I have not been able to repeat these errors on our systems or development environments.  Would anyone have any ideas, even to get the error to happen on our pcs so that we can move something forward?

Please let me know if there is more information that is needed from you to help out too!

**EDIT Note 1**

I should also mention, we put AfxMessageBox's in the program and it's crashing around if(!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo)).  We've created a basic MFC project that includes the same command and that program runs well on the target machine.

**Edit Note 2**

The systems our client is using is a Windows 10 64 bit operating system and a Windows 7 64 bit operating system.

Comment: Perhaps it's a DLL you missed to add to the installation? Are you using a function, or passing an argument to a function, that doesn't exist in the customers version of Windows?

Comment: 0x80000003 is a breakpoint exception.  Look in the Output window for a possible debug heap diagnostic.  Look at the disassembly window and stack trace to ensure the code didn't run away into oblivion.

Comment: I have checked to make sure those DLLs are on the system and they are there.  I will check what could possibly be calling those two, as I'm not entirely sure.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As for possible ways to track the crashes, get the users crash-dumps (the ["Dr. Watson"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Watson_(debugger)) dumps) and use some tool to examine them.

Comment: Are your client's PCs 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: The client PCs are 64 bit operating systems.

Comment: I've seen this error code 0x80000003 some time back on Windows XP machine where the issue was due to one of the corrupted system file. There was no work around other than reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Add a [minidump](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680369(v=vs.85).aspx) to your app and ask the user to send it to you after a crash happens.

Comment: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181.aspx): *"Starting with Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1), Windows Error Reporting (WER) can be configured so that full user-mode dumps are collected and stored locally after a user-mode application crashes. [...] To enable and configure the feature, use the following registry values ..."* No code required.

Comment: Thanks for the insight so far everyone.  Most of the items I've tried have been unsuccessful at this point.  I haven't tried the User-Mode Dumps just yet.  I'll be looking into additional options today.  Please feel free to keep the suggestions flying and I'll keep trying them until this is solved and I'll let you know how it happened. This has been a real head scratcher for me!

Comment: If any are wondering, we found a complete work around for this issue.  We are using the 32 bit version of the program.  The main reason we wanted to bring this up to 64 bit was to work with Microsoft Excel, but if I lined up the dlls appropriately with the program, we could use the 32 bit dlls with the 32 bit application, update the 64 bit dlls as needed, and use the 64 bit dlls with Excel.  It's a little messing around, but it solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

So here was the end result for how we resolved this issue.  Since we had a 32 bit version of the code working, the upgrade to 64 bit was for macros to work in Excel.  We resolved the issues by using the 32 bit application code and our 32 bit dlls and 64 bit dlls for the application.  The dlls are working in tandem and sharing the appropriate information between them.  This has made it so our customers can use this program with the newer versions of Excel.